# Unable to tag SCM when preparing a release using maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven-release-plugin

I'm having trouble preparing a release of my project using the maven release plugin.

SCM connection:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/myrepo</connection>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:svn:https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/myrepo
    </developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Release plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        <providerImplementations>
            <svn>javasvn</svn>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

All goes well until the SCM needs to be tagged:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
SVN tag failed.
Command output:
svn: E175002: unknown host
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/myrepo'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the subversion repository is not available using https?
For me it worked changing to the svn protocol:

```
scm:svn:svn://subversion.assembla.com/svn/myrepo
```